# How to make JS hide out smoothly and change px to %?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Credit to @Nick Brunt, after some editing and now this is exact what i want

px version: http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/9/ - working but the menu not hide out smoothly

% version: http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/10/ - not really working

but, wondering how to make it hide out smoothly and is that possible to change the unit of width from px to % ? while when i change to % it's not working... Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several syntax errors in your code, try this:

```
$("#openMenu").click(function() {
    var $menu = $("#menu");
    var $content = $("#content");

    if ($menu.is(":visible")) {
        $menu.hide().stop().animate({ width: '0%' }, 1000);
        $content.stop().animate({width: '100%'}, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $menu.show().stop().animate({ width: '20%' }, 1000);
        $content.stop().animate({ width: '80%' }, 1000);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/12/)

Comment: It does - your version had numerous syntax errors, and clicking the button did nothing at all.

Comment: Ooo.. it will work when i copy your code and paste on it. because i am new learner =P Thank you for teach =D but may i know how could i avoid the content box to drop down ??

Comment: @SLim Animate the height to 0 as well as the width, then hide the element, rather than hiding it then animating only the width to 0.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, but may i know how should i put the " .hide() " ?